# "String" contains function in C

Tags: c, strings

This function checks whether or not a substring `needle` exists in another string `haystack` and returns the position if it does or 0 if it doesn't, unless the position is 0 in which case, it won't be located.

Looking for ways to improve this code, specifically better error handling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t contains(const char * needle, const char *haystack);

int main(void)
{
    char *needle = "test";
    char *haystack = "This is a dinosaurtest.";
    printf("Position: %lu", contains(needle, haystack));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

size_t contains(const char * needle, const char *haystack)
{
    if(needle == NULL || haystack == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    long int first_char_pos = -1;
    size_t len_h = strlen(haystack);
    size_t len_n = strlen(needle);
    size_t i, j;
    size_t exist_count = 0;

    // Find the first character. If it doesn't exist, we're done.
    for(i = 0; i < len_h; i++)
    {
            if((haystack[i] == needle[0]) && (first_char_pos == -1))
            {
                first_char_pos = i;
                exist_count++;
            }
    }

    if(first_char_pos == -1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("First char match index: %li\n", first_char_pos);
    printf("Char: %c\n", haystack[first_char_pos]);
    size_t current_index = (size_t) first_char_pos;
    for(i = first_char_pos; i < len_h; i++)
    {
        if(haystack[i] == needle[exist_count] && (i == (current_index + 1)))
        {
            current_index = i;
            exist_count++;
        }
        printf("Exist count: %lu\n", exist_count); //<--Debugging
        if(exist_count == len_n)
        {
            return first_char_pos;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some examples to show exactly what you mean by saying "contains". I doubt that your code works as intended.

Comment: This already exists: `strstr()`. There's a safer version called `strnstr()`. You can find an implementation here: https://github.com/lattera/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/string/strnstr.c

Comment: @RolandIllig: why, can you explain?

Comment: Should `contains("tt", "test")` return true?

Comment: @RolandIllig That should return zero. It's like `strstr`, except it's returning the offset from the beginning of the string (and zero on failure).

Comment: Ok, next example: `contains("et", "test")`, what should it return?

Comment: @RolandIllig Zero. Do you think "et" is in "test" anywhere?

Comment: BUG found: `if((haystack[i] == needle[0]) && (first_char_pos == -1)) { first_char_pos = i; exist_count++; }` that will be true 0 or 1 times, not more.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Different for sure, but not safer. One is for null terminated strings, the other for null padded strings, which can be deceptively similar.

Comment: @Deduplicator  `strnstr()` will never try to read beyond `size`, and if your strings are broken for some reason, it will be safer.  I agree that in normal code one should never meet a non-NUL-terminated string where a NUL-terminated string is expected, but it may happen.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito If you have counted strings, why do you re-count them? If you don't have counted strings, where do you get the maximum count from? Either way, `strnstr()` is a square peg in a round hole at best, as your data isn't zero-padded strings.

Comment: @Deduplicator A string is written in an array of `char`.  You can use the size of that array (if you have it, of course) for the size as an upper bound.  The benefit is to avoid buffer overrun (UB), while it doesn't avoid reading uninitialized data if the string isn't NUL-terminated (not necessarily UB).

Comment: @CacahueteFrito So, you pay a not inconsiderable cost in usability *and* performance to mask data-corruption in some rare circumstances, instead of relying on your programs invariants, patching the data or reporting the error? That seems a bad idea all around.

Answer (score 5):

Just a couple of remarks:

- You should add a newline after the last line:

  ```
    $ ./nh
    First char match index: 18
    Char: t
    Exist count: 1
    Exist count: 2
    Exist count: 3
    Exist count: 4
    Position: 18 $
  ```
- I don't know what compiler you use but with when compiled with `gcc` and `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` you get:

  ```
  gcc -O2 nh.c -lm -o nh -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
  nh.c: In function ‘contains’:
  nh.c:25:15: warning: unused variable ‘j’ [-Wunused-variable]
   size_t i, j;
             ^
  ```
- Code formatting should be more consistent. For example, in this line you put a whitespace before `needle` but don't put a whitespace before `haystack`:

  ```
  size_t contains(const char * needle, const char *haystack);
  ```
- `%lu` is not a portable specifier for `size_t` type, you should use `%zu` introduced in C99.
- You said:

> returns the position if it does or 0 if it doesn't, unless the
>   position is 0 in which case, it won't be located.

This is really not good. For example, with this it returns 0:

```
char *needle = "This";
char *haystack = "This is a dinosaurtest.";
```

With this, it also returns zero:

```
char *needle = "non-existent";
char *haystack = "This is a dinosaurtest.";
```

You can't tell the difference between success and failure in this two
examples. Actually, `atoi()` has the same problem. I don't know what
operating system you use but maybe you could use `ssize_t` as the
return type if it's available and return -1 in case of failure.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to the previous answer by @Arkadiusz Drabczyk:

A simple, trivial implementation of `contains` could be done like this:

```
ssize_t contains(const char * needle, const char *haystack)
{
    char *needle_in_haystack;
    if(!needle || !haystack) return -1;
    needle_in_haystack = strstr(haystack, needle);
    return needle_in_haystack ? needle_in_haystack - haystack : -1;
}
```

Then, this program (with a few changes as mentioned above) should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

ssize_t contains(const char * needle, const char *haystack)
{
    char *needle_in_haystack;
    if(!needle || !haystack) return -1;
    needle_in_haystack = strstr(haystack, needle);
    return needle_in_haystack ? needle_in_haystack - haystack : -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *needle = "test";
    char *haystack = "This is a dinosaurtest.";
    char *haystack2 = "This does not contain the string.";
    printf("Position: %zd\n", contains(needle, haystack));
    printf("Position: %zd\n", contains(needle, haystack2));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

> Position: 18
>   Position: -1

Comment: I would remove the check that the input is not NULL, and just use a language extension for that (`__attribute__((nonnull))` in GCC). `NULL` is something that you would never expect as input for this function, and it adds one or two unnecessary lines of code. I would prefer to write in the documentation of the function something like: "If the input to this function is a NULL pointer, the behaviour is undefined.".

Comment: @CacahueteFrito The original code did it, and I want to strive for compatibility (who knows how the OP was using it?).

Comment: Missing include for `ssize_t`: `#include <sys/types.h>`. Another option would be to use `ptrdiff_t` instead, from `#include <stddef.h>`; you are actually returning a pointer difference: `? needle_in_haystack - haystack :`

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work. It returns `0` for `haystack` `"abbc"` and `needle` `"bc"`, even though `haystack` contains `needle`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the first loop and all the length calculations. Btw., the function doesn't succeed, if the first char is found, but only the second occourrence of the first char  fits with needle.

The task can be reduced to a few lines:

```
int contains(char *buf, char *needle) {
    char *src, *srch, *srcp;
    for(src=buf; *src; src++) {
        for(srch = needle, srcp = src; *srch && *srcp && *srch == *srcp; srch++, srcp++);
        if(!*srch) return src - buf;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What is a good way to get better at writing more compact, efficient C code like this? This sorta reminds me of K&R C.